# JPA 2.0 field annotation vs method annotation

Tags: java, database, jpa

in JPA 2.0 which is the difference between annotating a field and annotating a method (typically a getter)?

Example with field annotation

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id

    @OneToMany
    private RelatedEntity relatedEntity

    //getters and setters and possible other methods
    ...

}
```

Example with method annotation

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private RelatedEntity relatedEntity

    //getters and setters and possible other methods
    @OneToMany
    public RelatedEntity getRelatedEntity(){
           return relatedEntity
    }

    //other methods etc
    ...

 }
```

Comment: What is the difference ? In one you annotate the field and the other the method! For persistence there is no difference since JPA providers support both ways. Beyond that it is totally opinion-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `JPA` you can use both methods to map the columns of your table in your entity class; fields/methods access doesn't change anything from a schema generation point of view nor in terms of translated queries. Generally speaking field annotation is cleaner (frameworks like Spring encourages it), methods annotation can grant you more flexibility (like with inheriting from an abstract entity class).

Please notice that in your second example there is an error:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

    private Long id;

    private RelatedEntity relatedEntity

    //getters and setters and possible other methods
    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany
    public RelatedEntity getRelatedEntity(){
           return relatedEntity
    }

    //other methods etc
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From user point of view there is no difference until it is consistent, but using annotation in different places change behavior of JPA provider (hibernate, EclipseLink, etc.).

Place where annotation were set gives JPA provider information about which [access type](https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-2-access-annotation) you what to use. If you mix that setting annotations in both places then provider picks one and ignores rest. In example in your second listing hibernate will ignore `@Id` because you have `@OneToMany` on method and that means you prefer to use `AccessType.PROPERTY`.

Of course sometimes we don't want to use property access, because we have some extra methods that provides some logic and match to naming convention. Then we should use `AccessType.FIELD`.

In project you should use consistent style. Mixed style is valid, but you need to define `@Access` for almost all elements in your POJO.